# C# - Parse and read the JSON which has duplicate Keys

Tags: c#, json, parsing

I am trying to figure out how I can parse the below JSON and get the "text": "lawyer" out of it. I see that it has to many branching. i.e Arrays and Objects. I want to do this in C#. Here is the JSON:

```
{
  "status": "Succeeded",
  "succeeded": true,
  "failed": false,
  "finished": true,
  "recognitionResult": {
    "lines": [{
      "boundingBox": [140, 289, 818, 294, 816, 342, 138, 340],
      "text": "General information Com",
      "words": [{
        "boundingBox": [106, 290, 363, 291, 363, 343, 106, 343],
        "text": "General"
      }, {
        "boundingBox": [323, 291, 659, 291, 659, 344, 323, 343],
        "text": "lawyer"
      }, {
        "boundingBox": [665, 291, 790, 291, 790, 344, 665, 344],
        "text": "Com"
      }]
    }]
  }
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I parse JSON with C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6620165/how-can-i-parse-json-with-c)

Comment: Hi Karanvir - These aren't really 'duplicates' as each section has its own defined values that each can contain.  `words` has `boundingBox` and `text` on its own, but so does `lines` as well, also containing `words`.

Answer (score 0):

First use Quicktype.io to generate a native C# class:

```
public partial class Result
    {
        [JsonProperty("status")]
        public string Status { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("succeeded")]
        public bool Succeeded { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("failed")]
        public bool Failed { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("finished")]
        public bool Finished { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("recognitionResult")]
        public RecognitionResult RecognitionResult { get; set; }
    }

    public partial class RecognitionResult
    {
        [JsonProperty("lines")]
        public Line[] Lines { get; set; }
    }

    public partial class Line
    {
        [JsonProperty("boundingBox")]
        public long[] BoundingBox { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("text")]
        public string Text { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("words")]
        public Word[] Words { get; set; }
    }

    public partial class Word
    {
        [JsonProperty("boundingBox")]
        public long[] BoundingBox { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("text")]
        public string Text { get; set; }
    }
```

Then, [deserialize the JSON](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/DeserializeObject.htm) to an instance of the Result class (let's call it `result`) using Newtonsoft.

And then you can

```
result.RecognitionResult.Where(s => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(s.Text) && s.Text == "lawyer");
```

If you just want the first occurance, use `.FirstOrDefault()`